# Java Socket - InputStream read seems to hang

Tags: java, c#, inputstream, outputstream, networkstream

I'm porting some C# code to Java code and I done it right (hopefully) but I'm still clueless on the behaviour or what I do miss on the Java port.

Background: It's a server socket reading & sending packets (as a byte[]). I have no access to the client layer, but the structure is right on the server side (so the client can accept)

C# code uses NetworkStream to write/read.
Java code uses InputStream & OutputStream to write/read.

C# code: (the thread method is started via Thread.start)

```
public override void ReceivingThread(object o)
{
        Client client = (Client)o;
        PacketStream clientStream = client.PacketStream;
        byte[] clientBuffer = new byte[4096];

        packetHandler.SendFirstPacket(client);

        while ((!this.Stopped) && (clientStream.Read(clientBuffer, 0, 8) != 0))
        {
            if (BitConverter.ToInt16(clientBuffer, 6) > 0)
            {
                clientStream.Read(clientBuffer, 8, BitConverter.ToInt16(clientBuffer, 6));
            }

        Packet packet = new Packet(clientBuffer);
        Console.WriteLine($"RECV [{packet.PacketId:X4}] {BitConverter.ToString(packet.GetRawPacket(), 0, packet.DataLength + 8)}");
        packetHandler.HandlePacket(client, packet);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("outside of loop");
}
```

Scenario: Server sends first packet, client reads it and sends credentials(in this case), server checks them. To make it easier for now I send a packet with a code indicating that credentials are invalid (code -4 as a short -> 4002). The client accepts it immidiatly and the Thread is discarded. (the "outside of loop" is hit). The client doesn't hang, nor does the server.

I replicated or better to say, ported that code and functionality in Java.
Since in Java you cannot start Threads as methods in form of Thread extending etc. I'm starting the thread with help of Java8 & lambdas. (`new Thread(() -> receivingThread(client)).start();`)

```
@Override
public void receivingThread(Object o) {

    Client client = (Client) o;
    PacketStream clientStream = client.getPacketStream();

    byte[] clientBuffer = new byte[4096];

    packetHandler.sendWelcomePacket(client);

    while ((!this.stopped) && (clientStream.read(clientBuffer, 0, 8) != -1)) {

        if (BitKit.bytesToShort(clientBuffer, 6) > -1)
            clientStream.read(clientBuffer, 8, BitKit.bytesToShort(clientBuffer, 6));

        Packet packet = new Packet(clientBuffer);
        logger.info("RECV [" + String.format("0x%x", (int)packet.getPacketId()) + "] " + BitKit.toString(packet.getRawPacket(), 0, packet.getDataLength() + 8));

        packetHandler.handlePacket(client, packet);
    }
    logger.info("outside of loop");
}
```

NetworkStream.Read returns 0, Java InputStream.read returns -1 for eof.
The thing is, in the Java port, it hangs after the second packet is sent. Like somehow the read blocks in some not normal way. I think it's about a minute or something. Then the client throws an connection error instead of the code I sent with the second write.

The streams are setup in constructor of Client class which is passed down. The write and read operations are for raw data -> `read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size)`

Any ideas about it?
Why does it work on C# end and not Java? Does C# work with packets differently than Java? Any help is appreciated and thanks in forward!

P.S: Sorry for the long text :)

Comment: Something that might be idiomatic in C#, doesn't necessarily translate directly to Java (and vice-versa). The Java code looks odd to my eyes for example. However, you're probably inadvertently blocking on `read()` somewhere. I'd recommend following the logic with a debugger to see what's happening.

Comment: Thanks. Through debugging I saw that it failed somewhere else and that was at check sum creation, which resulted in wrong checksums being proceeded